# Pretty print XML using Jersey client

Tags: java, xml, pretty-print, jersey-client

How can I pretty print the XML **response** from Jersey Client?

Right now I am using a logging filter on Jersey Client with XML_FORMAT_OUTPUT set to true, but this pretty prints only the request message, not the response... Does the response need to be handled differently?

My code:

```
ClientConfig config = new ClientConfig();
config.property(MessageProperties.XML_FORMAT_OUTPUT, true); //pretty print xml

Client client = ClientBuilder.newClient(config);
client.register(new LoggingFilter(logger, true)); //enable printing entity in log
```

What I get in log is:

```
3 * Sending client request on thread Thread-2
3 > POST http://server:8080/
3 > Accept: application/xml
3 > Content-Type: application/xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<prov>
    <request type="get">
        <list>
            <subscriber id="170"/>
        </list>
    </request>
</prov>


3 * Client response received on thread Thread-2
3 < 200
3 < Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true
3 < Access-Control-Allow-Headers: x-requested-with, X-Auth-Token, Content-Type
3 < Access-Control-Allow-Methods: POST, GET, OPTIONS, DELETE
3 < Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
3 < Access-Control-Max-Age: 3600
3 < Content-Type: application/xml;charset=UTF-8
3 < Date: Tue, 26 Apr 2016 12:40:25 GMT
3 < Server: Apache-Coyote/1.1
3 < Transfer-Encoding: chunked
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?><prov><result type="get" failed="true"/></prov>
```